# how to fix wm_concat in oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

As wm_concat is deprecated in oracle 12C, i need to modify below query, i tried using LISTAGG but it did not work

```
SELECT WM_CONCAT(CLRR.CLNTNUM)
    || '#'
    ||WM_CONCAT(trim(trim(clnt.salutl)
    || ' '
    || trim(clnt.lgivname)
    || ' '
    || trim(clnt.lsurname)))
  FROM ODSLIFEASIA.CLRRPF CLRR,
    odslifeasia.clntpf clnt
  WHERE clnt.clntnum             = CLRR.CLNTNUM
  AND CLRRROLE                   = 'LF'
  AND clnt.validflag            IN ('1', '3')
  AND NVL(USED2B, 'X')          <> 'U'
  AND rownum                     <5;
```

I tried below code, but it did not work:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(CLRR.CLNTNUM,',') within group (order by CLRR.CLNTNUM)--WM_CONCAT(CLRR.CLNTNUM)
        || '#'
        ||LISTAGG(trim(trim(clnt.salutl,',') within group (order by CLRR.clnt.salutl)--WM_CONCAT(trim(trim(clnt.salutl)
        || ' '
        || trim(clnt.lgivname)
        || ' '
        || trim(clnt.lsurname)))
      FROM ODSLIFEASIA.CLRRPF CLRR,
        odslifeasia.clntpf clnt
      WHERE clnt.clntnum             = CLRR.CLNTNUM
      AND CLRRROLE                   = 'LF'
      AND clnt.validflag            IN ('1', '3')
      AND NVL(USED2B, 'X')          <> 'U'
      AND rownum                     <5;
```

I tried below code, but it did not work:

```
    SELECT LISTAGG(CLRR.CLNTNUM,',') within group (order by CLRR.CLNTNUM)--WM_CONCAT(CLRR.CLNTNUM)
    || '#'
    ||LISTAGG(trim(trim(clnt.salutl,',') within group (order by CLRR.clnt.salutl)--WM_CONCAT(trim(trim(clnt.salutl)
    || ' '
    || trim(clnt.lgivname)
    || ' '
    || trim(clnt.lsurname)))
  FROM ODSLIFEASIA.CLRRPF CLRR,
    odslifeasia.clntpf clnt
  WHERE clnt.clntnum             = CLRR.CLNTNUM
  AND CLRRROLE                   = 'LF'
  AND clnt.validflag            IN ('1', '3')
  AND NVL(USED2B, 'X')          <> 'U'
  AND rownum                     <5;
```

I am unable to get the output with `LISTAGG` but with `wm_concat` I am getting:

53155087,53155088,53155089,53155090#MR IONE underwriting,MR IONE     underwriting,MR IONE underwriting,MR IONE underwriting

The same i am expecting

Comment: Few people will be able to help you without running some SQL, so you might want to add some sample data to your question.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean ? Are you getting some error code, or returning not as you desired ? Btw, the query seems to have typo due to heavy parentheses at the end of `trim(clnt.lsurname)))`, and missing parentheses at the end of the third line.

Comment: Also `order by CLRR.clnt.salutl` (in the second LISTAGG) is not representing any column. It should be `order by clnt.salutl`

Comment: "It did not work" is not helpful. We don't have access to your data, we don't see what's on your screen, and we don't know what "it did not work" means. Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button, and explain *for each of your example queries* what "it did not work" means. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Concatenate values salut1, lgivname and lsurname at first, then use listagg(). It should be:

```
select listagg(clrr.clntnum,',') 
           within group (order by clrr.clntnum) || '#' ||
       listagg(trim(trim(clnt.salutl)|| ' '|| 
                    trim(clnt.lgivname)|| ' ' || 
                    trim(clnt.lsurname)), ',')
           within group (order by clnt.salutl)
      from odslifeasia.clrrpf clrr
      join odslifeasia.clntpf clnt on clnt.clntnum = clrr.clntnum
      where clrrrole           = 'LF'
        and clnt.validflag     in ('1', '3')
        and nvl(used2b, 'x')   <> 'U'
        and rownum             < 5;
```

I hope I did not make any typo. Also use `join`.

BTW: You are using different ordering for both lists, maybe it would be better to use the same?

Comment: Yep, wm_concat() function works in Oracle 11 and was replaced to listagg() in Oracle 12.

Comment: @Tomasz A few minor corrections - `LISTAGG` was introduced in 11.2.  And it didn't really replace `WM_CONCAT`.  `WM_CONCAT` was not *deprecated*, it was an internal, unsupported feature that we were never supposed to use.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting your query neatly will help you to know where the function arguments should be.

The `LISTAGG` syntax is:

```
LISTAGG( value, separator ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY columns )
```

Here, the `value` is the concatenation of salutation, first and last names and then the `separator` string should go after that. You had the brackets in the wrong places so that the separator argument for the `LISTAGG` function was inside the `TRIM` function.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(
         CLRR.CLNTNUM,
         ','
       ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CLRR.CLNTNUM)
       || '#'
       || LISTAGG(
            trim(
              trim(clnt.salutl)
              || ' '
              || trim(clnt.lgivname)
              || ' '
              || trim(clnt.lsurname)
            ),
            ','
          ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CLRR.clnt.salutl)
FROM   ODSLIFEASIA.CLRRPF CLRR
       INNER JOIN odslifeasia.clntpf clnt
       ON ( clnt.clntnum = CLRR.CLNTNUM)
WHERE CLRRROLE                   = 'LF'
AND   clnt.validflag            IN ('1', '3')
AND   NVL(USED2B, 'X')          <> 'U'
AND   rownum                    <5;
```

Answer (score 1):

WM_CONCAT has NOT been deprecated, it has been removed.  It was an unsupported and undocumented function in the database (even though it was part of the WMSYS schema [workspace manager] it was undocumented).  As such it was a function intended for Oracle internal use which means it could be removed at any time without notice.

As others have reported listagg() is still available and is a supported function in various releases of oracle starting with 11.2.  Let's look at a working example using the EMP table:

`SQL> select listagg(empno, ',') within group (order by empno) emplist from emp
2  /

### EMPLIST

7369,7499,7521,7566,7654,7698,7782,7788,7839,7844,7876,7900,7902,7934

SQL>`

To get a department listing:

`SQL) > select deptno, listagg(empno, ',') within group (order by empno) emplist from emp
2  group by deptno
3  /

```
DEPTNO E0MPLIST
```

---

```
    10 7782,7839,7934
    20 7369,7566,7788,7876,7902
    30 7499,7521,7654,7698,7844,7900
```

SQL>`

Hopefully this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own user-defined aggregate function as explained here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402.

And this is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BigStringConcat 
AS OBJECT
(
    runningStr      CLOB,
    
    STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize (actx IN OUT BigStringConcat)
        RETURN NUMBER,
        
    MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate (
                                            self   IN OUT BigStringConcat,
                                            value  IN     VARCHAR2)
        RETURN NUMBER,
        
    MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate (
                                            self          IN     BigStringConcat,
                                            returnValue   OUT    CLOB,
                                            flags         IN     NUMBER)
        RETURN NUMBER,
        
    MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge (self   IN OUT BigStringConcat,
                                        ctx2   IN     BigStringConcat)
        RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY BigStringConcat 
AS     
    STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize (actx IN OUT BigStringConcat)
        RETURN NUMBER
    IS 
    BEGIN
        actx := BigStringConcat(EMPTY_CLOB());
        RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
    END;
        
    MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate (
                                            self   IN OUT BigStringConcat,
                                            value  IN     VARCHAR2)
        RETURN NUMBER
    IS
    BEGIN
        self.runningStr := self.runningStr || value || ',';
        RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
    END;    
        
    MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate (
                                            self          IN     BigStringConcat,
                                            returnValue   OUT    CLOB,
                                            flags         IN     NUMBER)
        RETURN NUMBER
    IS
    BEGIN
        returnValue := RTRIM(self.runningStr, ',');
        RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
    END;
        
    MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge (self   IN OUT BigStringConcat,
                                        ctx2   IN     BigStringConcat)
        RETURN NUMBER
    IS
    BEGIN
        self.runningStr := self.runningStr || ctx2.runningStr;
        RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
    END;


END;
/

CREATE or replace FUNCTION cn_concat (INPUT VARCHAR2) RETURN CLOB
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING BigStringConcat;

SQL> SELECT LENGTH(CN_CONCAT(object_name))
2  FROM all_objects;

LENGTH(CN_CONCAT(OBJECT_NAME))
------------------------------
                       1251401

Elapsed: 00:00:03.04
```

Tested on Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0.